# QML How to stop the transition animation?

Tags: qml

Sample code:

```
Button{
   text: "stop"
   onClicked: p1p2Aniamtion.stop();
}
Rectangle {
  id: rect
  states: [
        State {
            name: "p1"
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; x: 0; y: 0}
        },
        State {
            name: "p2"
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; x: 500; y: 0}
        }
    ]
    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "p1"; to: "p2"; reversible: true
            NumberAnimation{ property: "x"; duration: 5000}
        }
    ]
}
```

Here i have a rectangle and make it move from point `p1` to point `p2`,
if button clicked, i want the animation of transition force to stop.

I tried to stop `NumberAnimation`, but looks like the `NumberAnimation` is bound with `Transition` , so anyway to control the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force it, to move to the end position, try:

```
   onClicked: {
       var s = rect.state
       rect.state = ''
       rect.state = s
   }
```

If you want to reset it to the original position try:

```
onClicked: {
       rect.state = ''
   }
```

If you want it to stay where it is try:

- Add a property e.G. tempX: x
- Add a state e.G. pause with a propertyChange { target: rect; x: tempX }
- onXChanged: tempX = x

Switch to state 'pause' onClicked

```
Button{
    y: 400
   text: "stop"
   onClicked: {
       var s = rect.state
       rect.state = 'pause'
       //rect.state = s
   }
}

Button{
    y: 400
    x: 100
   text: "run"
   onClicked: rect.state = (rect.state === 'p1' ? 'p2' : 'p1');
}

Rectangle {
  id: rect
  width: 80
  height: 80
  property int tempX: x
  onXChanged: tempX = x

  states: [
        State {
            name: "p1"
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; x: 0; y: 0}
        },
        State {
            name: "p2"
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; x: 500; y: 0}
        },
        State {
          name: 'pause'
          PropertyChanges { target: rect; x: tempX }
      }
    ]
    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "p1"; to: "p2"; reversible: true
            NumberAnimation{ property: "x"; duration: 5000}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! great answer.
Another problem: i add animation for resuming(eg: pause ⇒ p1), if i resume the animation, the duration need to recalculate.

Comment: That should be easy. You have the starting point (x: 0) the end point (x: 500) and your current position. So you calculate the percentage of your movement so far (pos - start) / (end - start) and multiplicate that with your duration. (Not tested, but somehow like this, it should work...)